# What do reviewer and assignee mean in pull request?

Tags: github

In GitHub, when creating a pull request,

what do reviewer and assignee mean?

What are their differences and relations?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

For a pull request, you can now "request a review explicitly from collaborators, **making it easier to specify who you'd like to review your pull request.**"

Assignees, on the other hand, "clarify who is working on specific issues and pull requests."

In sum, the difference is whether you'd like to ask someone to work on fixing an issue or contribute to a pull request (**assignee**), versus asking someone to quality check your work (**reviewer**).

Sources:

- https://github.com/blog/2291-introducing-review-requests
- https://help.github.com/articles/assigning-issues-and-pull-requests-to-other-github-users/